# How to stop loop,when it find the correct answer?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a projectile calculator, so it really need to change the way to calculate again & again until it is done.

but now i'm facing with a problem..again :(

```
var Height = Number(document.getElementById("Height").value);
var Velocity = Number(document.getElementById("Velocity").value);
var Range = Number(document.getElementById("Range").value);
var First = ((((Math.SQRT2 * Velocity) + (Math.sqrt(19.6) * Velocity * Height)) * Math.cos(0.785398163)) / 9.8);
document.getElementById("First").innerHTML = First;
if(First < Range) 
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "Need more velocity to success on this range";
    else
    {
    for(var i = -1.570796327; [>>>****HELP****<<<] ; i+0.000000001)
    {
    ((((Velocity * Math.sin(i)) + Math.sqrt(Velocity * Math.sin(i) * Velocity * Math.sin(i) - 19.6 * Height))) / 9.8) * Velocity * Math.cos(i))
    }
    }
```

ALL of this code is make for finding a correct angle for projectile shooting, and I use "i" for angle

1. Please look on [****HELP****] that's the problem...I want to stop this loop after my calculation is equal to "Range" but I really have no idea to do that :(
2. After I got the correct "i" how can i print it to show the answer?

or anyways to make this code better or faster calculation?

Ty for every help :)

Comment: use `break` statement, will "jumps out" of a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use break to exit the loop if you reached the expected value/range. You may also check if your result is near your range within +/- a value because you probably won't get the exact same values as you defined for Range.

```
for(var i = -1.570796327; i < MaxValue ; i+0.000000001)
{
   result = ((((Velocity * Math.sin(i)) + Math.sqrt(Velocity * Math.sin(i) * Velocity * Math.sin(i) - 19.6 * Height))) / 9.8) * Velocity * Math.cos(i));
   if(result >= Range) break;
}
```

Comment: In this case it might be a bit safer to do `if(result >= Range)` or do an epsilon check as you suggest

Comment: then after it break how can I use "i" for next calculation? any suggestion? thank you

Comment: Just use it for your next calculation. You will have the value at that point you exited the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use this where you want to break

```
if "condition fullfilled inside for-loop"
 return false;
```

To print it why not use:

```
console.log(i);
```

Answer (score -1):

In jquery and js, if you are using loops (for, while, $.each) than `return true` will be equal to `continue` in PHP, and `return false` will be equal to `break`. Since you are using simple `for` loop, than there is enough to use `return false` to break this loop.

Comment: If they're equivalent, why not just use `break`? It's more obvious what the code is doing in that case

Comment: Because there is no `break` in js, thats why.

Comment: [Yes there is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break). Please do your research